# How to Install Gutters Under This Roof

Tags: waterproofing, gutters

Looking for advice on how to install (or if I should install) gutter under this roof.

This is a back porch that sticks out from the house. Unfortunately the basement does extend under the porch, so the main reason for wanting to drain away water here is to  keep the runoff away from the basement.

I already had issues with the basement wall being forced inwards by freezing/expanding water over the years (house was built in 1930). I would like to prevent this from happening again.

The roof doesn't seem to have a normal fascia board, with the roof edge sticking about 3 inches past the existing board. Maybe I should use hangers with straps? Or maybe I should use shims behind the gutter to position them in the correct place?

The other issue is where to put the downspout. The ends of the porch are away from any sort of structure to attach a downspout to. I think I probably need to wrap the gutter around the corner of the roof and have the downspout come down by the house. I would have a similar problem here: how to I hang the gutter?

[image: Roof without normal fascia board]

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is not that uncommon.

For the hangers, you may use [roof mounted brackets](https://www.kmsheetmetal.com/shop/Aluminum-Universal-Roof-Mount-for-Gutter-Bracket-p55250251) / [hangers](https://www.kmsheetmetal.com/shop/15-Fascia-Mount-Half-Round-Gutter-Aluminum-Bar-Hanger-p55250240) or you may add blocking behind them as the other answer suggested.

You can also have a custom made gutter that has an angled flange that sticks under the shingles and sits on the roof, or just have a deeper gutter that sits against that fascia.

As suggested by @riseagainst using the columns or rain chains is your best bet.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to thicken up that 1" board (a 2x4 + 1x4 would do), paint it white and then attach gutters to it.  That would be the way I do it.

As for the downspout portion, I have seen people use a chain hanging from the hole to the ground (an example I googled up : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49ZNQPmLWeU)

Comment: beautiful porch by the way !  Love the looks of it.

Answer (score 0):

[Roof mounted hangers](https://www.riversidesheetmetal.net/gutters/hangers/half-round/1.html).

[image]
If using a rod, you can install half-round gutters or k-style gutters (even custom gutters).

If looking specifically for half round gutters, other hangers are available like [these hangers with longer backs](https://www.riversidesheetmetal.net/gutters/hangers/half-round/8.html) that can be bent into shape onto the roof or you can have custom made ones.

For the downspout, you can use one of those posts as the structure, just have the gutter pitched from both sides to it, or you could do chains as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a DIY site but I have found it cheaper and longer lasting to have continuous gutters installed, having the gutters drop at the posts would not be a problem. Over the years I have seen some very unique designs with some being supported by the roof decking, I don't know how long those lasted as I moved to another state shortly after my neighbor had that type of gutter installed. I have also seen chains that directed the water to a funnel shaped pipe at the ground level when I first saw this I thought it was a hack or a joke but was amazed to see low well it worked and it looked neat when raining. So you might want to get a quote from a respected gutter company and discuss your options then evaluate if it would be a good idea to DIY or have it done.

Answer (score 0):

Using an earth anchor to tie the downspout to the ground may solve your downspout problem - but I'd probably want to tie the downspout to the posts, and use flexible downspout elbows to connect to the gutter. You can direct the water towards the side of the house at the ground. Jeff and riseagainst both had solid ideas for the gutter itself.

Another option is to dig a drain trench, fill it with decorative stone, and make it look like a landscape feature. I actually did this myself to resolve a drainage problem caused by my driveway being graded higher than my house (saved me from having to dig much deeper holes in gravelly clay for window wells).